# JButtons dont get the Correct Size and Location

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Hello I have a Problem with some Buttons

I would like to create a simple GUI with JButtons but when I start the App the Buttons Positions and Size changes every Time when i start the App.
I use this Code:

```
    usr_in.setSize(120,40);
```

usr_in.setLocation(10,40);
usr_in is a JButton

Created Like this:

```
JButton usr_ro = new JButton("Users");
```

and here I set them:

```
menu.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 3));
menu.add(usr_ro);
```

I use the Libs:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.*;
```

thanks for help

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the type of your `menu` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, two questions: what is the type of `menu`? And is `usr_in` the same as `usr_ro`? The names obviously aren't the same, but your wording implies that they are meant to be the same.

From what you've provided so far, the problem seems to be that you're trying to set the location of the button(s) in two different ways. In one place, you're using `setLocation()`, which "is specified by the x and y  parameters in the coordinate space of this component's parent." ([source](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation%28int,%20int%29))

Later, you're using a `GridLayout`, which sets locations in its own way: fitting them to the grid. ([source](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/GridLayout.html)) I don't think the behavior is well-defined if you apply both, though I am a little surprised that you're not getting the same unwanted behavior every time.

Answer (score 0):

I find the best practice is to put your button(s) in a JPanel, which uses a FlowLayout.  Your button shouldn't varies in size if you're not fiddling too much with the parent container layout.